# SQL Server - show one column's values into single row with new columns

Tags: sql-server

I want to show values from 6 rows for a particular column in single row with 6 columns for 6 values..

Actually we have a column (TestValues) where we are storing 6 values split by '##@##'. But we want it to be shown in different textboxes on UI, but we have to split them in SQL Server stored procedure only.

Current Output using this query:

```
SELECT Code,Reason, 
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(500)'))) AS TestValues
FROM
(
SELECT Code,Reason, CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(TestValues,'##@##','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM dbo.Information where Logged_ID = 1001
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

I have tried below query but it's not working ... Please let me know where I am wrong.

```
select * from 
(   
    select *, rank() over (partition by TestValues order by code) rank from
    (
        SELECT Code,Reason, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(500)'))) AS TestValues
        FROM
        (
        SELECT Code,Reason, CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(TestValues,'##@##','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
        FROM dbo.Information where Logged_ID = 1001
        )t
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
    ) r
)tab1
pivot
(
max([TestValues]) for rank in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) pv
```

[image]

Comment: Where are those column headings coming from, and how are you determining the order of the results (I see no ID/Lable column for example)? To be very specific, what determines the order of your column `TestValues` is `12345`,`23456`,`''`,`123456`,`1234567`,`12345`? I can't think of have `ORDER BY` clause that would be able to create that order (especially as `12345` is both at the end and start). Also, please don't post data as an image, provide it as `text`. You have enough reputation to know that. 

Comment: If you are asking about the desired o/p image.. the headers are just text I put. I need order as same as in current o/p image. And it was quicker to post images..(I know though).

Comment: Then, how do you achieve that order with an `ORDER BY` clause? With the data in that image it would be impossible, thus which column a value would be assigned to would be completely random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, currently, as it stands, the order you'll get is completely random, due to a lack of identity, ordering, label. Thus, you could use this, but the results will change every time the query is run:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleData(Code varchar(15),
                            Reason varchar(4),
                            testValues varchar(7));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SampleData (Code,
                            Reason,
                            testValues)
VALUES ('Phlebotomist','test','12345'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','23456'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test',''),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','123456'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','1234567'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','12345');
GO
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Reason ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN --PARTITION BY is a guess, NEWID as order is random as currently stands 
    FROM dbo.SampleData)
SELECT Code, Reason,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS BusinessUnit,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS MainUnit,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS [Location],
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS CustID
FROM RNs
GROUP BY Code, Reason;
GO

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SampleData;
```

This easy to fix though, provided that the order of the entries is always the same. Add an `IDENTITY` column (you might use something else, but you nned *something* to be able to determine the order):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleData(SomeID int IDENTITY(1,1), --Something to ORDER BY!
                            Code varchar(15),
                            Reason varchar(4),
                            testValues varchar(7));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SampleData (Code,
                            Reason,
                            testValues)
VALUES ('Phlebotomist','test','12345'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','23456'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test',''),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','123456'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','1234567'),
       ('Phlebotomist','test','12345');
GO
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Reason ORDER BY SomeID ASC) AS RN --NOw we have an order we can rely on!
    FROM dbo.SampleData)
SELECT Code, Reason,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS BusinessUnit,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS MainUnit,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS [Location],
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN RNs.testValues END) AS CustID
FROM RNs
GROUP BY Code, Reason;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SampleData;
```

Don't forget, data in a table is stored in a heap. It has no "inherent order".

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish huh?

Comment: I written query that matches with your query.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu Really appreciate it. I created a temp table inside stored proc.. Working well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to look at this intermediate select?

```
select *, rank() over (partition by TestValues order by code) rank from
    (
        SELECT Code,Reason, 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(500)'))) AS TestValues
        FROM
        (
        SELECT Code,Reason, CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(TestValues,'##@##','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
        FROM dbo.Information where Logged_ID = 1001
        )t
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
    ) r
```

There is the answer in the `rank` value - it is `1` for every row. That is why only group `[1]` in your pivot is filled with data (note, there is a correct `max` value as you defined; note, max from "strings" not numbers).

`partition by TestValues` - `partition` restarts ordering for each `TestValues` value. "Partitions" means "groups" here. Rank per group, row number per group and so on. If partitioning is applied to unique column each row will have rank/rk = 1 - because ranking/rn would restart for every row (every partition).

Here is an example of different window functions applied to dataset like yours: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/31103

One of them will fit your needs.

By the way, "rank" function is supposed to give same result for different rows in a partition sometimes. Take a look at the difference between `rank` and `rn` function results for dup rows (see my comment at sqlfiddle).

And I'd take something else from `dbo.Information` to keep test results in the right order. Ordering by name (which is the same for every test in a group) or test results (which has nothing to do with test order) would possibly give each time different output for the same arguments and probably incorrect because of wrong ordering.